# Ethernet "link negotiation", manual vs ignore?

Tags: network-interface, ethernet

I think I understand "Automatic" and "Manual", but what is "Ignore"? If I choose "Ignore", then the speed setting becomes unavailable. If the speed is not automatically decided nor manually set, what speed is chosen when "Ignore"d?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't tell what software produces the image you shown, I'll assume it is some interface to *networkmanager*.

If link negociation is *ignored* then… no change to **the already set** connection parameters will be committed **by the utility you are currently running**.

Now, what does this *already set of connection parameters* consist in ?

- Whatever you would have specifically specified in whatever .conf-like file or forced by whatever other networkmanager-agnostic application running. (But this is unlikely since… why would you be running networkmanager then ?)
- Much more likely ; whatever NIC's factory settings or default set by its driver at init time.

While, in your apparent case of a 1 Gbps NIC, this is likely to mean 1 Gbps / Full-Duplex… it could just in fact be 0 Gbps / Half-Duplex or whatever… in between…

Comment: agreed that the speed settings will be determined by the hardware and/or driver, I think it is confusing to say the ethernet connection will be not be configured, it will be configured just not by using use the link auto negotiation protocol.    It is important to note that it is possible to use auto negotiation  but also limit the advertised link modes.  Unfortunately this UI and/or networkmanager doesn't readily expose that capability.

Comment: The screenshot is the network manager of Gnome. I think it is included in Ubuntu by default. I thought that it is so well-known that I did not have to mention its name (and it did not nave a noticeable name anyway).

Comment: Its name seems to be [nm-connection-editor](https://linuxhint.com/nm-connection-editor-ubuntu/). Bad name, in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks @toppk. You are correct regarding the confusion I had imprudently suggested. I updated my answer

Comment: @DamnVegetables : No worry! But… you know… not everyone here use Gnome not to say that… not everyone here use a graphical utility in order to set network configuration parameters… ( I'm one of those ;-) )